# How to attempt to delete records without terminating on error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that is used in several other tables as a foreign key. If the table is referenced in only one specific table, I want the delete to be allowed and to cascade on delete. However, if there exists references in other tables, the delete should fail.

I want to test the referntial integrity of this with my data set by attempting to delete every record. No records should be deleted except for the last one. However, when I attempt to delete every record, it errors (as expected) and terminates the rest of the statement.

How can I write a script that attempts to delete every record in a table and not terminate the statement on the first error?

Kind Regards,

ribald

EDIT:

The reason I would want to do something like this is because the business users have added a lot of duplicate data (ie: Search for someone and click the "Add As New" instead of the "Select"). Now we may have 10 people out there that only have a name and no relation to the other tables. I hope this clearifies any confusion.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit. (1)  It sounds like you have T_Parent, which has T_ChildCascade, and T_ChildNoCascade1, and T_ChildNoCascade2.    (2) Is your normal use case to delete everything or a single record?  (3) What does a DataSet have to do with the question? (4) What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Excellent questions:

1) Your assumptions are correct T_Parent is referenced by several T_Child tables. One is T_ChildCascade and Many are T_ChildNoCascade.

Comment: Cool.  What about the other questions i asked ?

Comment: 2) The normal case of deleting a record in the application is to delete each reference seperately. I couldn't have cascade delete on many of the tables due to a circular cascade tree. The situation I'm describing is merely a test situation for a script I was writing to be absolutely sure that it will delete only one record.

3) The data set is merely a pre-populated datbase that I will use to test on. Sorry for any confusion. 

4) Version number is 10.50.1600.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around with different ideas. Here is the most straight forward way. However, it is pretty costly. Again, this is to attempt to delete unused duplicate data. 1,000 records took 8 minutes. Can anyone think of a more effecient way to do this?

```
DECLARE @DeletedID Int

DECLARE ItemsToDelete SCROLL CurSor For
SELECT ID FROM ParentTable

Open ItemsToDelete

FETCH NEXT FROM ItemsToDelete INTO @DeletedID
     While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        --ATTEMPT TO DELETE
        DELETE FROM ParentTable WHERE ID = @DeletedID;
    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH
        --DO NOTHING
    END CATCH

        --FETCH NEXT ROW
    FETCH NEXT FROM ItemsToDelete INTO @DeletedID
END


Close ItemsToDelete

Deallocate ItemsToDelete
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this with a grain of salt:  I'm not actually a DBA, and have never worked with SQL Server.  However:

You're actually up against two different rules here:

1. Referential constraints
2. Business-specific (I'm assuming) 'delete-allowed' rules.

It sounds like when the referential constraints (in the children tables) were setup, they were created with the option `RESTRICT` or `NO ACTION`.  This means that attempting to delete from the parent table will, when children rows are present, cause the failure.  But the catch is that you want, on a specific table, to allow deletes, and to propogate them (option `CASCADE`).  So, for *only* those tables where the delete **should** be propogated, alter the referential constraint to use `CASCADE`.  Otherwise, prevent the delete with the (already present) error.

As for dealing with the 'exceptions' that crop up... here are some ways to deal with them:

1. Predict them.  Write your delete in such a fashion as to *not* delete something if the key is referenced in a set of the children tables.  This is obviously not maintainable in the long term, or for a heavily-referenced table.
2. Catch the exception.  I doubt these can be caught 'in-script' (especially if running a single .txt-type file), so you're probably going to have to at least write a stored procedure, or run from a higher-level language.  The second problem here is that you can't 'skip' the error and 'continue' the delete (that I'm aware of) - SQL is going to *keep* failing you every time (...on what amounts to a random row).  You'd have to loop through the *entire* file, **by line** (or possibly set of lines, dynamically), to be able to ensure the record delete.  For a small file (relatively), this *may* work.
3. Write a (set) of dynamic statements that uses the information schema tables and lookups to exclude ids included in the 'non-deletable' tables.  Interesting in concept, but potentially difficult/expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Well, each statement in SQL is considered as transaction, therefore, if you try to delete several records, and you hit a error considering integrity rules, each and every change you made so far will be rolled back. The thing you might do is to write query which will delete data from referencing table (table which has value from  foreign key (T_child table in your case) first, and then delete data from T_parent table.

In total: First check T_child  table for records which you want to delete, and then delete records from T_parent table, to avoid transaction failure.

Hope this helps.

(Correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here.   There is a bit of ambiguity in your question, so I want to re-iterate your use case first (and I'll answer your question as I understand it).

**Use Case**

Database consists of several tables   T_Parent,  T_Child1,  T_Child2, T_Child3. A complete set of data would have records in all 4 tables.  Given business requirements, we often end up with partial data that needs to be removed at a later time.  For example, T_parent and T_Child2 may get data, but not TC1 and TC3.

I need to be able to check for partial data and if found remove all the partial data (T_Parent and T_Child 2 in my example, but it could be TP and TC3, or other combinations).

---

**@ribald - Is my understanding correct?**

- Comment on my understanding and I'll write out an answer.  If the comments aren't long or clear enough, just edit your question.
- you said "cascade" in terms of delete (which means a very specific thing in SQL server), but in your later description it sounds more like you want to delete all the partial data.
- "Cascading" is something that is available, but not really something you turn on and off based on conditions of some data.
- when you said "dataset" you didn't mean  an ADO.NET Dataset, you just meant test data.
- I assume you aren't looking for a good way to test, you just want to be sure you have data integrity.