# Delete unattached data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to be able to delete items from a table that isn't referenced in any other table. The project I've been working on has rapid development, so I don't really want to have to keep the script up to date.

My original solution is simply loop through every item in the desired table and attempt to delete (see below). Is there a better way to do this without looping or having to maintain the query of items to be deleted?

My old post: [How to attempt to delete records without terminating on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958842/how-to-attempt-to-delete-records-without-terminating-on-error/7967046#7967046)

```
DECLARE @DeletedID Int

DECLARE ItemsToDelete SCROLL CurSor For
SELECT ID FROM ParentTable

Open ItemsToDelete

FETCH NEXT FROM ItemsToDelete INTO @DeletedID
    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        --ATTEMPT TO DELETE
        DELETE FROM ParentTable WHERE ID = @DeletedID;
    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH
        --DO NOTHING
    END CATCH

    --FETCH NEXT ROW
    FETCH NEXT FROM ItemsToDelete INTO @DeletedID
END


Close ItemsToDelete

Deallocate ItemsToDelete
```

Comment: I donot really get it why you have to use cursor,you can just do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need an `ugly cursor` to do this simple task you can simple do something like this

```
DELETE TargetTable  --<-- Table from where you deleting records
FROM TargetTable LEFT JOIN Table1    --<-- Checking records in Table1
ON TargetTable.ID = Table1.FK_ID
LEFT JOIN Table2                 --<-- Checking records in Table2
ON TargetTable.ID = Table2.FK_ID
WHERE Table1.FK_ID IS NULL 
AND Table2.FK_ID IS NULL
```

and same way you can add as many as table you want to check against.

Comment: Yeah, the cursor is ugly. I am afraid your solution is the best, but I really don't want to have to maintain the query due to ongoing development. The target table is probably referenced in over 50 tables currently.

Comment: @ribald and trust me looping through 50 tables and scanning them with a cursor will be a lot slower then joining 50 tables in one query :)

Answer (score 0):

I donot really get it why you have to use cursor,you can just do this

```
Delete from 
Table1 
left join table2 
  on table1.ID =Table2.ID 
where table2.ID is null
```

Assuming table1 as the main table and Table2 as the other table

If you want to make sure it doesnot lockup the system put the delete statement in the Transaction serializable

Comment: Right. Essentially, there is a table "People". We have issues where business users just create "People" but don't actually use them in any of our businesses. This causes us to end up with duplicates that clutters our search screens. We periodically need to remove these entries.

While some tables that have a relationship to "People" have a cascade delete, some do not. For instance if I have some person that is associated with a membership.

Comment: In my scenario, I don't want to keep having update the script because far too often there is some new table that references the "People" table. I was hoping for a way that would not require maintenance.

Otherwise, I'm going to have to have every programmer responsible for keeping this cleanup script up-to-date.

Comment: IF you have primary key and foreign key rleation betwen the tables then you can build a dynamic sql using the script in this link  [click here](http://sqlbisam.blogspot.com/2013/11/list-of-foreign-keys-referencing-table.html), basically you need to write a cursor to loop through each record ouputed from the query in link and then use the table_name column to build the dynamic sql, Hope this helps